# Lines missing in 3d scatterplot

Tags: python, plot, graph, 3d, line

I can't find the reason why my plot shows no lines....

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(n):
    ax.scatter(lys[i][0], lys[i][1], lys[i][2], c='b', marker='o')
ax.plot(x, y, z,'bo', label='Self-avoiding random walk')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the markers in `ax.plot` to `'bo'`, which corresponds to blue circle markers only. If you want lines between the markers, you probably want `'b-o'`, as [defined in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) (check out the 'Format Strings' section under 'Notes'). You need to define the format string as `'[marker][line][color]'`.

Simple example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = y = z = [0, 1, 2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, 'b-o')
plt.show()
```

Returns:

[image: Example plot]

Comment: thx for the input. but it doesn't solve my problem :(
looks exactly the same with 'b-o' (or no 'bo' at all for that matter)

I also tried
````linestyle='solid', linewidth=2````
doesn't do anything either

Comment: Ah, that's a shame! Sorry to hear it. What version of matplotlib are you using? Does the example code I posted work on your computer? (I tried adding a label and a legend too, and it still works for me on v3.8.3)

Comment: @igapo16 This is a long shot, but did you try adding `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`  just after `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` ? Sometimes, that fixes weird issues with 3D plots for me (although you don't use it explicitly, I think it overrides `ax.plot`)

Comment: not a longshot :) I imported Axes3D before too, but all python did was complain that it is an unused line.

and yes, weirdly your code works fine for me, line and all

Comment: Strange! Are you plotting straight from a script? Or using a notebook or ipython or something else? Sorry, I'm out of ideas xD

Comment: whole program created by myself from zero. But it's fine. I'm just going to leave it like that. The professor himself tried to solve it but couldn't. So I guess he won't mind this little "pretty" detail missing, if the rest of the program is working anyway :)

Thank you for trying xD

Comment: No worries! Thanks, if you figure or out, I'd love to know what went wrong in case I encounter the same issue! Good luck!